Why Does עלה Mean 'Page'?
I have seen numerous sages refer to a page as עלה. Yet the normative way to refer to a page is עמוד or דף. What is the etymology of this usage?

Consider the English: leaf of a book

And Latin folio, from folium

@JoelK that's a valid answer. Why do you leave a comment?

Is it the normative way? Just because that's what's used to refer to pages in gemara doesn't mean much. Also, עמוד originally means column, and דף I think means a flat surface (like a tabletop). Both are borrowed to mean page
